# Aspect Oriented Programming with StructureMap.DynamicInterception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aop, structuremap

I implemented a console app that uses DynamicInterception on structure map, I follow the example on the page [StructureMap DynamicInterception](http://structuremap.github.io/dynamic-interception/).
Now I'm trying to pass the code to a asp.net MVC site but I get the following error

Decorator Interceptor failed during object construction.  See the inner exception:

> 1.) DynamicProxyInterceptor of ITSector.Site.Core.Controllers.HomeController with interception
>   behaviors: ITSector.Library.Aspect.LoggerInterceptor
>   2.) ITSector.Site.Core.Controllers.HomeController
>   3.) Instance of ITSector.Site.Core.Controllers.HomeController
>   4.) Container.GetInstance(ITSector.Site.Core.Controllers.HomeController)

The inner exception is:
Specified type is not an interface
Parameter name: interfaceToProxy
With the stacktrace:

```
at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, Object target, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget[TInterface](TInterface target, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IBuildSession , IContext )
```

I use the Structure.MVC5.Update nuget as the Dependency Resolver.
Can anyone give me any hint on how to implement it to intercept calls on controller methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StructureMap is expecting an interface in the `For<T>()` method, but you're passing it `HomeController`, which is a concrete class.

You have a couple of options to get it working. You can attach your `LoggerInteceptor` to all controllers with `For<IController>()`. If you only want to attach the logger to some of your controllers, you can create a new interface specifically for the logged controllers, like `For<ILoggedController>()`, and ensure the desired controllers inherit from ILoggedController.